# If $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism, then $\phi(1_G) = 1_H$ - proof verification

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I have two proofs on "if $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism, then $\phi(1_G) = 1_H$".

The first one is the one in the lecture notes:

> Let $\phi(1_G) = h$. Then $1_Hh = h = \phi(1_G) = \phi(1_G1_G) = hh$. So $h = 1_H$.

Which is fine. Here is my proof, which is a copy of a proof for **isomorphisms**:

> By definition, $1_Gg = g = g1_G$. Then $\phi(1_Gg) = \phi(g) = \phi(g1_G) \implies \phi(1_g)\phi(g) = \phi(g) = \phi(g)\phi(1_G) \implies \phi(1_G) = 1_H$, by definition.

Which is fine if $\phi$ is an isomorphism.
But I feel that this is wrong in the case that $\phi$ is a homomorphism since we do not have bijectivity, so we cannot assume that for all $h \in H$ there exists a $g \in G$ such that $\phi(g) = h$.

Am I correct in thinking this?
Also, is it okay to use the proof for homomorphisms for the isomorphism case?

Comment: The proof is correct since these are groups. If $xy = x$ for any pair $x,y\in G$ then in fact $y = 1_G$. This uses invertibility of the elements though (it fails for monoids).

Comment: Yes, you are correct, you would need surjectivity for your proof to work.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Which proof are you referring to? If it's the first, I get why it works.

Comment: @Ennar Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Your proof works because you show that the element $y=\phi(1_G)$ satisfies $yx = x$ for some $x\in H$ and thus $y = 1_H$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I've made an edit to attempt to clear up the (very understandable) misunderstanding that I think we're having.

Comment: What is missing from your proof is that it is no longer quite by definition but by a property of groups which is good to know anyway.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft As Ennar above confirmed, we also require surjectivity, so this approach doesn't quite work.

Comment: @IrregularUser We only need surjectivity for the "by definition". As Tobias points out, in groups we have $(\exists x)(yx = x) \implies y = 1$.

Comment: @IrregularUser, I agree with Tobias, with the modification as suggested the proof goes through, but it seems to me what you tried to use is that $\forall h\in H\ h\phi(1_G) = \phi(1_G)h = h$ which would give $\phi(1_G) =1_H$ by definition and uniqueness of neutral element.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, he was pointing out what makes the proof tick, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second proof is correct, but not for the reason you state.

It is incorrect to conclude that $\phi(1_G) = 1_H$ because $\phi(1_G)$ satisfies the definition for $1_H$. For that, you need $\phi(1_G)h = h\phi(1_G) = h$ for *all* $h\in H$, which as you and Ennar noted, requires surjectivity.

However, as Tobias mentions in the comments, by the virtue of the fact that you have $\phi(1_G)\phi(g) = \phi(g)$, that is enough to finish the proof. Since we are working with groups, we know that $\phi(g)$ is invertible. Then we have
$$\phi(1_G) = \phi(1_G)1_H = \phi(1_G)\phi(g)\phi(g)^{-1} = \phi(g)\phi(g)^{-1} = 1_H.$$

Answer (score 3):

In order to see where your proof fails, consider the situation where $G$ is a group and $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$ is considered as a semigroup under multiplication. Actually we consider the semigroup $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ under componentwise multiplication, which has $(1,1)$ as identity.

The map $\varphi\colon G\to \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ defined by $\varphi(g)=(1,0)$ certainly satisfies $\varphi(g_1g_2)=\varphi(g_1)\varphi(g_2)$, but it is false that $\varphi(1_G)$ is the identity of the codomain.

The moral of this is that you *need* to use the group properties. The case of isomorphisms is different: your argument would be fine if $\varphi$ is surjective.

---

The proof in the book is of course correct. Moreover, it uses the minimum it can.

The *only* element you know in $G$ is $1_G$; so if the result is true, it can be proved using just that element. It relies on a simple lemma.

> *Let $G$ be a group and $x\in G$; if $xx=x$, then $x=1_G$.*

Indeed, from $xx=x$, we get $(xx)x^{-1}=xx^{-1}$; by definition of inverse and by associativity, we get $x=1_G$.

Now you can apply the main property of $1_G$, that is, $1_G1_G=1_G$; so
$$
\varphi(1_G)=\varphi(1_G1_G)=\varphi(1_G)\varphi(1_G)
$$
So you get $y=\varphi(1_G)\in H$ that satisfies $y=yy$; by the lemma, $y=1_H$.